# Run values of one dataframe through another and find the index of similar value from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes both consisting of a 1 column with 62 values each:

```
Distance_obs = [    
0.0
0.9084
    2.1931
    2.85815
    3.3903
    3.84815
    4.2565
    4.6287
    4.97295
    5.29475
    5.598
    5.8856
    6.15975
    6.4222
    6.67435
    6.9173
    7.152
    7.37925
    7.5997
    7.8139
    8.02235
8.22555
    8.42385
    8.61755
    8.807
    8.99245
    9.17415
    9.35235
    9.5272
    9.6989
    9.86765
    10.0335
    10.1967
    10.3574
    10.5156
    10.6714
    10.825
    10.9765
    11.1259
    11.2732
    11.4187
    11.5622
    11.7041
    11.8442
    11.9827
    12.1197
    12.2552
    12.3891

    12.5216


    12.6527
    12.7825


    12.9109

    13.0381

    13.1641


    13.2889

    13.4126

    13.5351

    13.6565


    13.7768


    13.8961


    14.0144


    14.0733
]
```

and

```
Cell_mid = [0.814993
1.96757
2.56418
3.04159
3.45236
3.8187
4.15258
4.46142
4.75013
5.02221
5.28026
5.52624
5.76172
5.98792
6.20588
6.41642
6.62027
6.81802
7.01019
7.19723
7.37952
7.55742
7.73122
7.9012
8.0676
8.23063
8.39049
8.54736
8.70141
8.85277
9.00159
9.14798
9.29207
9.43396
9.57374
9.71152
9.84736
9.98136
10.1136
10.2441
10.373
10.5003
10.626
10.7503
10.8732
10.9947
11.1149
11.2337
11.3514
11.4678
11.5831
11.6972
11.8102
11.9222
12.0331
12.143
12.2519
12.3599
12.4669
12.573
12.6782
12.7826
]
```

I want to run each element in `Distance_obs` to run through the values in `Cell_mid` and find the corresponding index of nearest value which matches the element.

I have been trying using the following:

```py
for i in Distance_obs:
        Required_value = (np.abs(Cell_mid - i)).idxmin()
```

But I get

```
error: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, could be as follows:

- Use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), passing "nearest" to the `direction` parameter.
- Now, from the merged result select column `Cell_mid`, and use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a `pd.Series` where the values and index of its original `df` (here: `df2`) are swapped.

```
df['Cell_mid_index'] = pd.merge_asof(df, df2, 
                                     left_on='Distance_obs', 
                                     right_on='Cell_mid', 
                                     direction='nearest')\
    ['Cell_mid'].map(pd.Series(df2['Cell_mid'].index.values, 
                               index=df2['Cell_mid']))

print(df.head())

   Distance_obs  Cell_mid_index
0       0.00000               0
1       0.90840               0
2       2.19310               1
3       2.85815               3
4       3.39030               4
```

So, at the intermediate step, we had a merged `df` like this:

```
print(pd.merge_asof(df, df2, left_on='Distance_obs', 
                    right_on='Cell_mid', direction='nearest').head())

   Distance_obs  Cell_mid
0       0.00000  0.814993
1       0.90840  0.814993
2       2.19310  1.967570
3       2.85815  3.041590
4       3.39030  3.452360
```

And then with `.map` we are retrieving the appropriate index values from `df2`.

**Data used**

```
import pandas as pd

Distance_obs = [0.0, 0.9084, 2.1931, 2.85815, 3.3903, 3.84815, 4.2565, 
                4.6287, 4.97295, 5.29475, 5.598, 5.8856, 6.15975, 6.4222, 
                6.67435, 6.9173, 7.152, 7.37925, 7.5997, 7.8139, 8.02235, 
                8.22555, 8.42385, 8.61755, 8.807, 8.99245, 9.17415, 9.35235, 
                9.5272, 9.6989, 9.86765, 10.0335, 10.1967, 10.3574, 10.5156, 
                10.6714, 10.825, 10.9765, 11.1259, 11.2732, 11.4187, 11.5622, 
                11.7041, 11.8442, 11.9827, 12.1197, 12.2552, 12.3891, 12.5216, 
                12.6527, 12.7825, 12.9109, 13.0381, 13.1641, 13.2889, 13.4126,
                13.5351, 13.6565, 13.7768, 13.8961, 14.0144, 14.0733]

df = pd.DataFrame(Distance_obs, columns=['Distance_obs'])

Cell_mid = [0.814993, 1.96757, 2.56418, 3.04159, 3.45236, 3.8187, 4.15258, 
            4.46142, 4.75013, 5.02221, 5.28026, 5.52624, 5.76172, 5.98792, 
            6.20588, 6.41642, 6.62027, 6.81802, 7.01019, 7.19723, 7.37952, 
            7.55742, 7.73122, 7.9012, 8.0676, 8.23063, 8.39049, 8.54736, 
            8.70141, 8.85277, 9.00159, 9.14798, 9.29207, 9.43396, 9.57374, 
            9.71152, 9.84736, 9.98136, 10.1136, 10.2441, 10.373, 10.5003, 
            10.626, 10.7503, 10.8732, 10.9947, 11.1149, 11.2337, 11.3514, 
            11.4678, 11.5831, 11.6972, 11.8102, 11.9222, 12.0331, 12.143, 
            12.2519, 12.3599, 12.4669, 12.573, 12.6782, 12.7826]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(Cell_mid, columns=['Cell_mid'])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well but why does it stop after index 4? I mean last two elements of Distance_obs [14.0144, 14.0733] can still be characterized as being close to 12.786 (the last element of Cell_mid).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the prints. In my answer, I'm *printing* [`df.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html); this is just to give an idea of what the data looks like. The entire `df` will have all the matches. Just do `print(df)` and you'll see that it extends all the way to `14.07330` at index `61` matching `61` from `df2` (so, indeed: `12.7826`).